# replace parameter name show on screen?

Tags: parameters, abap, sap-selection-screens

When I'm defining a parameter, like:

```
 PARAMETER pa_date TYPE d DEFAULT sy-datum.
```

How do I change "pa_date" to something else when the app is launched? I want to change it to something like "choose date".

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Correct Menu Path is:

Goto (Alt-G) -> Text Elements (T) -> Selection Texts (S)

Once there you can Type in the Text you want OR click the "Dictionary Ref." Checkbox.  Doing this will keep your report selections a bit more standard, provided that you use the correct dictionary definition.

Comment: is this the only solution? I need to find a solution for this case but using code, is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 3):

in SE80 or SE38 in the menu go to "jump --> texts --> selection texts" 
there you can set a text for every parameter field.

Answer (score 3):

I think the menu path is edit->text->selection texts.  In there you'll find the ability to change the text for selection screen items.

Answer (score 0):

Goto (Alt-G) -> Text Elements (T) -> Selection Texts (S)

Once there you can Type in the Text you want and then Activated.

Once you done come back to main screen and activated main screen and run (f8)

you got the result what you want.