# Change parameter name on selection screen to a real text

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm trying to replace the parameter name shown on the [selection screen](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenselection_screen.htm).

For example I have:

```
PARAMETERS pa_age TYPE age_type DEFAULT '18'.
```

It shows `PA_AGE` on the screen.

How to change it to `How old are you?` for instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace parameter name show on screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783374/replace-parameter-name-show-on-screen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace parameter name show on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783374/replace-parameter-name-show-on-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via menu `Goto->Text Elements->Selection Text`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to define a text via Goto->text elements->selection text.

If you develop in another language as you execute your code, you need also a translation.

Comment: To complement the answer, the report must be active so that 'pa_age' appear in the report texts screen, and to translate you must translate from the original report language to the desired language. Also you can add ICON codes with the selection texts to display a little icons along with your text.

Comment: is this the only solution? I need to find a solution for this case but using code, is there such a possibility?

Comment: @Abapito Perhaps you can try something with `` AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.  LOOP AT SCREEN.`` to modify the text. At least you can change some settings, I'm not sure about the text.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. You can only change name but no text or i can't do it.